# GWT RPC possible in window closing handler?

Tags: gwt

I'm listening for a window close event:

```
closeHandlerReg = Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {
  @Override
  public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

The documentation says that no UI can be shown in that callback. What about GWT RPC calls? I'm trying to make one, but it isn't showing up on the server (either in breakpoints or log statements).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that GWT RPC is asynchronous and the calls to RPC services return immediately. In this case the window is closed before the browser has a chance to send the underlying XMLHTTPRequest.

If it's absolutely necessary you should be able to hand-craft calling some sort of servlet (not GWT RPC) with a "synchronous" XMLHTTPRequest. Have a look here for an example: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2005/12/15/433278.aspx

But really you shouldn't be doing anything of this sort in the `window.onunload` or `window.onbeforeunload` (these are the underlying DOM events for CloseEvent and ClosingEvent for the Window. Perhaps there is a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to notify the server that the connection is closing. Do you have a suggestion for an alternate method?

Comment: There is no "connection". That's just not how web apps work. But if you can't think of another way to accomplish what you want without contacting the server, you can try the synchronous XMLHTTPRequest example I provided. It just can't be done with GWT RPC.

Comment: Well, if I'm using web sockets, there's more of a sense of a constant connection, is there not?

Answer (score 2):

The use case you have should be possible. When you make the RPC call in the closeHandler it should arrive at the server, because while it returns directly, it has started sending the data, and set a callback to wait for the result. However the callback will fail because the connection is lost because the window is closed. But that is no problem as you only want to notify the server. So the question might be what are you sending? and does it work at all, when you send it at some other point in the code, not in the closeHandler?

Comment: I'm just trying to send a notification that the user is leaving the page. You're correct that I don't care about the callback. The GWT RPC call works fine at other points in the code.

Comment: In our case the call gets to the server sometimes - presumably depending on whether the necessary objects have been destroyed yet. Adding an "are you sure you want to leave the page" dialog gives it enough time to successfully send the call (using Window.addWindowClosingHandler and setting event.setMessage(...) to any string). Unfortunately this is not a good solution as the extra click would get very annoying. I don't know of a way to have the dialog auto-hide after a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still - maybe someone faces the same issue.

RPCs won't work in the closing handler as already discussed. This workaround worked for me:

In the onClose method, do something like:

```
Window.Location.replace(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "rpcCall?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2);
```

whereas "rpcCall" is the name of the rpc url you have set in your web.xml file. Of course, a random number of parameters may be passed within the URL.

Then, in your server-side implementation of your rpc interface, you can override the doGet method:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String param1 = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("param1"), "UTF-8");
    String param2 = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("param2"), "UTF-8");

    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And another solution: Don't do an rpc call on window closing, but a regular http call that can then be handled by a custom servlet on the server side.

In your GWT module, do something like this:

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
            sendWindowClosed(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "teardownservice");
        }
    });


    private native void sendWindowClosed(String url)
    /*-{
        var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
       }-*/;
}
```

In the server-side servlet, you can then handle this call:

```
public class TearDownServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        .... whatever you want ....
    }
}
```